# CSV file manipulation

Tags: bash, csv, export-to-csv

The below line represent an simple line of a CVS file that I need to manipulate.

```
....column-n    column-m
---------------------------------
....0x65AFB4C6, 0x27D47C0
```

From the above I must produce the next output:

0, 101, 175, 180, 198, 0, 39, 212, 124, 0

In other words I must split each hexadecimal value into bits and each bit to be converted to decimal number comma separated like the following:

```
0x65AFB4C6 becomes
0x  65     AF     B4    C6 which is converted to decimal
0  ,101  , 175  ,180  , 198
```

I know how to grep the entire column but how to I split every two characters and convert them to decimal? Any idea?

Comment: Can you post the output including the `.....` and `------` and `column-n` you are expecting? Are the `....` really a part of the input?

Comment: How should `0x27D47C0` be splitted? `27` `d4` `7c` `0` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following script with comments inside:

```
# pipe our input
cat <<EOF |
....column-n    column-m
---------------------------------
....0x65AFB4C6, 0x27D47C0
EOF
# first extract the numbers from input
# print the numbers on separate newlines appended with two 00
sed -E 's/0x([[:xdigit:]]+)/\n00\1\n/g' |
# filter lines starting with two 00
grep '^00' |
# make each number have a separate line
sed -E 's/../&\n/g;' |
# remove empty lines, there will be some
sed '/^$/d' |
# convert hex lines into decimal lines
xargs -I{} printf "%d\n" "0x{}" |
# print the lines separated by comma
paste -sd,
```

Produces the following output:

```
0,101,175,180,198,0,39,212,124,0
```

Tested at [paiza.io](https://paiza.io/projects/LxTA0-hSgICA6Vnq3YGLjQ?language=bash)